# How to query the following xml using XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath

This is the xml file

```
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I'm trying to get all the text in the `title` and `author` tags under the "web" category

I tried using

`//book[category="WEB"][//author or //title]//text()`

But this does'nt work

what is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**one possible way :**

```
//book[@category="WEB"]/*[self::author or self::title]/text()
```

**brief explanation :**

- `//book[@category="WEB"]` : find `book` elements, anywhere in the XML document, having `category` attribute value equals `WEB`
- `/*[self::author or self::title]` : find direct child elements of such `book`, where the child name equals `author` or `title`
- `/text()` : from such `author`/`title`, return the direct child text nodes

Comment: Thanks, and is there any way i can some formatting inside the XPATH response? in this case for instance `{title:'XQUERY Kick start', author:{'James McGovern','Per Bothner','Vaidyanathan Nagarajan'}` etc  if its not possible, can you suggest a supplementation that does this in just a single query? or i'd have to run seperate queries to get the details

Comment: XPath is the most basic technology around XML. It has very limited tools when it come to data manipulation, so I guess you can't do the formatting in XPath.

Comment: Or if you meant by 'formatting' is to construct a more specific XPath using more complex criteria, please explain it clearly, preferably in a separate question. That will avoid misunderstanding of the requirement and poluting this thread with unrelated -to the original question- discussion. I will be happy to help there. Thanks

Comment: @har07 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626299/how-to-format-the-following-xpath-output